# Specifiyng html file to execute the Javascript function in

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector

I have 2 HTML files: A.html and B.html. The purpose is to count the number of specific DIVs in A.html and display this number once B.html is opened.

A.html contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="elem1"></div>
<div class="elem2"></div>
<div class="elem2"></div>
<div class="elem2"></div>
<div class="elem1"></div>
<div class="elem2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

B.html contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="CntrElem2()">
The number of elem2 in A.html is: <span id="myNum"></span>.
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript (in style/js/scripts.js) function is:

```
function CntrElem2() {
      var NumOfElem2 = document.querySelectorAll(".elem2");
          document.getElementById("myNum").innerHTML = NumOfElem2.length;
    }
```

So, the idea is - when I open B.html, it calls for the CntrElem2 function from scripts.js, which in turn should go and count the number of class="elem2" in A.html (in my case = 4) and display it. What I obviously get is = 0 (since CntrElem2 counts for elem2 in the HTML file it was called from, i.e. B.html and not A.html). How can I specify which HTML file I want querySelectorAll to apply on? Thanks!

Comment: you will need to use something like fetch (ajax) on b.html. It will load the content of a.html and you can then use javascript to scan through the contents.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read the A.html document with a fetch, put the html in a div and query the div using querySelectorAll, change your function to the following:

```
async function CntrElem2() {
  let aHtml = await (await fetch('A.html')).text();
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = aHtml;
  let numOfElem2 = div.querySelectorAll(".elem2");
  document.getElementById("myNum").innerHTML = numOfElem2.length;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I got the idea, but somehow it doesn't work for me: https://plnkr.co/edit/MiSV9rcy9OjTrmOs?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview=B.html

Comment: In your plnkr the fetch is loading the wrong document (it's basically a plnkr 404 html page). Have you tried it outside of plnkr on your own computer with A.html and B.html in the same folder.

Comment: I tried it on my computer, but it doesn't pass the first line (with let aHtml). I broke this into three lines:
let url = 'A.html'; 
let response = await fetch(url); 
let commits = await response.text();
and the problem is in the lines with await. If I remove the await, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Are your A.html and B.html in the same folder? And you didn't remove 'async' before function? (Because it works locally on my computer.)

Comment: Are you running it from a local web server or just opening in your browser? Some browsers might block fetch from loading local files if you are just opening it in your browser. I would look at your browser's console as it might show you errors.

Comment: If you're using VSC you could use an extension like LiveServer to run it :)

Comment: Ok, now I see. imvain2 was right, fetch was blocked by the browsers when I just opened the B.html in them. I uploaded the htmls and js to my website and it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you got it to work!

Comment: @Yojix31 I'm glad that it worked out. So for future knowledge, running javascript from the file system and not from a web server will run into security restraints when trying to access local resources. If you don't want to keep having to upload to a web server to test it out, you can do something like Thomas recommended if you are using Visual Studio Code or I just use XAMPP on my computer as it allows me to also run a web server/apache/php etc

Comment: @imvain2 Thank you very much for this additional info. I appreciate that. And thank you both again for your help!

Comment: "*put the html in a div*" - that's not a good way to parse an entire document. You should not need to associate the contents with the current document either. Rather, use [a `DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) or at best [`createHTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument).

Comment: @Bergi Why isn't it a good way? And do note that the div is never added to the DOM - so not in any way associated to the current document - and is a local variable so it will be garbage collected right after running the function. And the solution works fine. So unless you can show me that using DOMParser och createHTMLDocument would be faster I can't see that it shouldn't be a good way.